# Connecting to bebop parrot drone via wifi with dronekit

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

I have a parrot bebop drone and I was curious if you can use the connect() method from dronekit to connect to it with the wifi that is built into the drone. connect() has connection string to use if connected to windows via usb or 3DR Telemetry Radio but not wifi. Just curious if there is a way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Derek - I've recently thought of doing this exact same thing. Have you tried it? I do not have a bebop (1/2), but AFAIK the drone should broadcast a wifi signal that you can connect to. I've done this with `pyparrot` and a mambo, but need more control/sensor functionality, so started looking at the bepop+dronekit. Please let me know if you've tried this. Thanks!